# What should I do with my unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078664/can-magento-use-a-session-variable-in-a-cache-key) a couple of years ago, and although I had some answers, none were usable (one was a misunderstanding of the question, and another offering an answer to a similar problem but that wouldn't work for the question I asked). The way I see it I have three options:

1. Accept the closest answer, even though it doesn't work as an answer to the question.
2. Delete the question. It's no longer one I need answering and as the page doesn't include an answer it doesn't seem to be much help to anyone else.
3. Leave it alone. Even though it irks me to have an unanswered question floating around, and it's just going to disappoint anyone who finds it through a search engine.

What's the correct, Stack-Exchangian way to handle it?

Comment: Regarding option 1, if an answer didn't help you, there is no reason to accept it.

Comment: a 4th option can be `start bounty`.

Comment: @Kedarnath Tricky - I no longer work at the company where this issue came up. I couldn't test a solution in the time I have available even if one were posted.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do is to keep it open, post any updates you have if you are still working to solve the problem, and let other give them any update or possible/exact solution for the problem.

You should not delete the question, even if doesn't have an exact answer(it does have a closest answer, someone might figure out something from those).

I also faced a similar scenario regarding a problem with a telerik control. I kept it open, and I didn't get a proper answer even after quite some days. Even a bounty didn't come up with an answer. Finally I figured out a solution, posted it as answer, and accept my own answer.